# Correct English words for trade 'source item' and 'destination item'

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

First of all, I hope I'm on the correct site asking a question, usually I'm around on Stack Overflow itself.

So here's the story: I am designing a database table involving trading and I'd like to use the correct words, the table involves at least:

- A user that wants to trade his item.
- The item he wants to trade, codenamed `sourceItem` for now.
- The item he wants to trade his item to, codenamed `destinationItem` for now.

What are the correct English words for `sourceItem` and `destinationItem`? I sadly don't even know it for Dutch (my language), so cannot translate it either.

**Edit** to clarify: I am looking for the genuine English naming of the words I've asked, I am *not* looking for a variable name or something of that kind.
I'm sorry if this question looked too much like a "How should I name this variable?"

Comment: Your question is off topic here as seen in the help ages _Naming, including naming programming variables/classes_ - the choices you made sounds OK to me. BronObject/DoelObject in Dutch - the latter perhaps better contain the word target than destination

Comment: @mplungjan I believe it is still a genuine question. Maybe I filled the question itself too much with the programming background, but that is just the background information.

Comment: I do not make the rules. I just let you know why this may be downvoted/closed by those who find such things important

Comment: As a side note, please stop misspelling "English". We can't be fixing it every time. Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'll do my best to avoid that in the future, I am usually not that concentrated on the precise grammar., I'll keep in mind for this site.

Comment: Neither strike me as perfect, but both strike me as appropriate and useful. Indeed, sometimes (my colleagues tell me) the word whose dictionary definition most perfectly matches the purpose is not as useful in such contexts as term composed of widely used words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When bartering, one party "offers" to trade. If the other party accepts this "consideration" the trade is "complete". The transaction is described as a "bartered" exchange.

**Offer**
n. an expression of readiness to do or give something if desired.

**Consideration**
n. a payment or reward.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `availableItem` and `targetedItem`.

I think these terms describe the requirements in a better way, as *source* and *destination* are not usually associated with items. However, it is a language and one may or may not agree with me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for the genuine English naming, not for variable names.